# Django: how to change a base object to an alone subclass object?

Tags: python, django, class, inheritance, model-view-controller

Now I'm working with python django.

I have derived a Model class from user:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Customer(User):

    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=14)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'customer_user'
```

#### Question

Now comes the question, I have some normal user object, which is not yet a `CustomerUser` object.

```
>>> john = User.objects.get(username='john')
>>> hasattr(john.customer)
False
```

Infact the *john* object has a row in the user table in database, but has no row in the customer table.

I want to change john into a `Customer` object, i.e. adding a row of customer, pointing the parent link to the initial user object row.

I tried the following code, but did not work?

```
>>> Customer.objects.create(user=john, mobile='1234')
```

Is there any nice way to do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options, as described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model):

1. Make your `Customer` model a [proxy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) for the `User` model:

```
class Customer(User):

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Then any instance of `User` is also an instance of `Customer`. Note that you probably don't want to set a custom `table_name` in this case because both models operate through the same table.

2. Make your `Customer` a profile model that has a one-to-one relationship with the core `User` model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class Customer(models.Model):

        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        mobile = models.CharField(max_length=14)
```

Then:

```
john = User.objects.get(username='john')
if not hasattr(john, 'customer'):
    Customer.objects.create(user=john, mobile='1234')
```

The second approach seems to me to be a better fit for your use case.